# Why does the center of the image vary from one Android device to another?

Tags: android, center, splash-screen

First, This is `style/splash_screen.xml`

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="htt..." 
            android:opacity="opaque">

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/colorSplash"/>

    <item
        android:width="100dp"
        android:height="100dp"
        android:gravity="center">
        <bitmap
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="fill"
            android:src="@drawable/logo_512" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

And below code is a part of `layout/activity_splash.xml`

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http...
    tools:context="com.example.SplashActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/splash_logo"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:src="@drawable/logo_512"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I put the logo image to the center of the each screen
And with `AndroidManifest.xml`,

```
<activity
    android:name=".SplashActivity"
    android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
```

I let my app to show the splash screen with initial loading image when app clicked from the launcher.
But the problem is, it has different logo position between style file and layout file.
When I start the app from my GalaxyS8,
initial loading screen's logo image is lower than splash screen, as low as *statusbar_height*.

But When I start the app from my AVD,

initial loading screen's logo image is higher than splash screen one, higher as *statusbar_height*.

```
resourceId = getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
statusbar_height = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
```

I still don't get it, why this kind of difference happens with the same code, different device. 
How can I get solve this problem?

PS: because I need to add animation to the splash screen, I need to let launch image and splash screen both have to have same logo position.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **LinearLayout** instead of **ConstraintLayout** and use *layout_gravity* attribute inside *ImageView* as:

```
<LinearLayout>
   <ImageView
      android:layout_gravity="center" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are loading the image from XML. What happens is that Android scale the image for you based on the resources that you provided.

Also, you are using DP sizes aka density pixels, those are affected by the device screen density.

One quick way to have the same result on all the devices is to load your image from `resources/raw` or `resources/nodpi` folder and use PX instead of DP sizes. However, this solution is highly unrecommended. Instead what you should do is to create a dedicated resource for each of your app supported resolutions. Also if you like to be more dynamic you can use [vector graphics](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html).